# will visual studio 2019 lag on a core 2 duo PC

Tags: hard-drive, cpu, performance, visual-studio-2010

Okay am aware that Visual Studio 2019 has been optimized for the latest processors and devices running a solid state drive. I have lots of work to do and the only machine currently available is a an old machine running a `seventh generation core 2 duo 7500 series processor`. The physical Ram of the machine is 2 GB and I forced it to run windows 10 operating system. The hard drive is 500 Gigs. I intend to run Visual Studip 2019 32 bit on this system, so to what speed extent  will this be operable in terms of expected bottlenecks arising from the hard drive?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community,  Question edited

Comment: The system requirements for Visual Studio 2019 are [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/system-requirements).  The system you describe does not meet the minimum requirements.

Comment: From the hard drive only?  That depends on SSD or HDD.  The bottom line is that you can do development on just about any machine since most of the time *should be* spent in the text editor aspect of your IDE.  Your disk is going to churn from all of the swapping that is going to be needed working against 2GB of ram, but it should work (even though it is below specs).  What do you have to lose?  TRY IT rather than asking people if it will work or not.  I have worked under worse conditions.  IMHO, use 32bit windows (not just vs) with only 2gb.  It will mostly suck.

Comment: @Senor CMasMas, Okay Thanks.. The problem with the HDD swap is that it's always slower than the RAM. Will increasing the RAM making it better?

Comment: Yes OF COURSE adding ram will make it better.  Even 4gb vs 2gb will make all of the difference in the world.  If windows doesn't have enough ram when programs ask for it, it pretends by using your hard drive as ram (called virtual memory).. this is even slow with an SSD drive but VERY SLOW with an HDD drive.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas, Thanks for the tip, I implemented it and its running fine , its operable